# How to run the next CMD command in HTA after installing Nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, activex, hta

I use a simple HTA file with CMD commands within JavaScript to install Nodejs module and then run my Nodejs app by the module.

For example

```
<script>
var WShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
WShell.run('cmd /c npm install pm2 -g');

WShell.CurrentDirectory = 'C:\\Users\\Username\\my_app_folder';
WShell.run('cmd /c pm2 start app.js --watch');
</script>
```

The problem is the `pm2 start` command runs before the module is installed with the `npm install pm2` command.

How to resolve the problem?

Of course, I can check if a file of the module is already exists, but I don't know how to check out which file of the module is the last one to be installed.

Maybe it's possible to get the CMD response and then check if it's like "added XX packages...", that means the module is fully installed. But how to get the CMD response?

ps. I use Windows binary version of Nodejs

Comment: Execute cmd synchronously, `WShell.Run('cmd /c npm install pm2 -g', 0, true);
`. If you want to see the command window, use `1` instead of `0` as the second argument.

Comment: @Teemu thanks! What does the third argument mean?

Comment: It is a boolean, true means the script waits for the program to finish, false says to continue script without waiting for the called program.

Comment: @Teemu can we get also the status of CMD and display on HTA page as loading bar? If yes, then how to?

Comment: Unfortunately I've no experience of checking "cmd status", so I can't say.